# Change HTML attribute depending on screen size

Tags: html, css

I'm using [Slidebars](http://plugins.adchsm.me/slidebars/) as extension to create off-canvas menus for my site. Custom width can be set using `data-sb-width` attribute. I have set it to 370px like this:

```
<div class="sb-slidebar sb-left sb-width-custom" data-sb-width="370px"></div>
```

On mobile i need to change it to 280px, but I don't know if this is possible with CSS media queries. Help would be needed.

Comment: You have to use Javascript (or jQuery or the likes) for this. You can use media queries only for setting values of CSS properties.

Comment: I don't think CSS can change a data attribute [yet](http://andydavies.me/blog/2012/08/13/what-if-we-could-use-css-to-manipulate-html-attributes/). But javascript can -- I suggest using [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) so you can conditionally set data attributes based on viewport size.

Comment: Deleted my bad answer (apologies for the confusion!). **No, you can't use CSS.**

Comment: @Harry Thanks for your response. Could you show little sample how I'm going to approach with this solution.

Comment: @AleksiTappura: Here is a [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/pC3B9/) (a very rough one). Click on the button and see the changed HTML in the console log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this is an HTML attribute and not a CSS style, you won't be able to directly use CSS media queries for this.

I see several options to explore:

- set the `data-sb-width` using Javascript or jQuery (before you setup the slide bars)
- use two slide bars with different widths, and use media queries to hide one or the other (not quite sure the slide bar script will like that)
- give the width as a percentage rather than a fixed width, but that may be difficult to control